# Kafka Consumer from jar/ide not working

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api

Good Day

I have a problem accessing an external IP that has the kafka topic I consume.
From my VM I can create a consumer and access the topic --from-beginning -> Works.

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server XXX.XXX.X.XX:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Unfortunaelty when I try accessing it through my IDE(Intellij) or .jar file (Which is on the same VM(Ubuntu)), it does NOT read from the external topic ???

```
    // configure kafka consumer
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "XXX.XXX.X.XX:9092");
    properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

    // create a kafka consumer
    final DataStream<String> consumer = env_in
            .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>("test", new    
             SimpleStringSchema(), properties));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of kafka are you using? And do you get errors or nothing at all?

Comment: How are you checking that you are not getting any messages? Are you executing the flink job properly? I mean did u add the env_in.execute() ?  and also are you using event time for processing?

Comment: How do you know it's not working? The snippet you've shared looks okay, but there are many things that can cause a Flink to not produce any output. You might want to study the relevant Flink training exercise --
 http://training.data-artisans.com/exercises/toFromKafka.html  -- and see if the sample solution runs properly. Or if you post your complete app we might spot the problem.

Comment: Running Kafka_2.11

Comment: I have another question with my sample code "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338574/learning-flink-kafka-simple-app-in-parallel" but it is for localhost(Works), if I add an external IP it does not work